# Delete TableViewRow in Titanium mobile

Tags: javascript, titanium, tableview

I have a TableView, but don't want to use the builtin swipe-to-delete functionality for various reasons. So, I have a button in that row that should delete the containing row. How would I do that? The TableView object has a deleteRow() function, but it requires the index of the row to be deleted, and as far as I know, there isn't a way to get that from a TableViewRow object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could set the row index as a property of the button when you create the button

you could put the event listener on the whole row, detect when the source object is the button and then you would have the index and the button click event for the delete.

there are multiple approaches, some code would help me to direct you to the best solution

Comment: I can access the row from the button, I just set a custom ._parent property. But there isn't a TableViewRow.index or something is there? The problem with setting the index as a property is that the index will change when rows are rearragned/deleted.

Comment: You can list for the click event on the entire table, one listener per row is not necessary. Take Aaron's approach and check if the source is one of your buttons (hint: you could detect based on the title of the source, or some other identifying property on your delete buttons). Next, use the event's "index" property to determine which row was acted upon.

For example:
    table.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title: 'Clicked Index: ' + evt.index,
            message: 'You clicked on a row!'
        }).show();
    });

Comment: Thanks, that's great, hadn't thought of that before

Comment: the way to check for which item was selected is to set the `id` property on the button. I usually defined it for all of my items..